# netcoreapp 2.1 how to keep app running as background in linux

Tags: c#, .net, linux, .net-core, terminal

I want to know how to make my project run in the background of Linux without stopping if I close the Linux console, i want to keep my project running without close if terminal is closed.

**For example:**

[Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iurXB.png)

If I close terminal dot net run process kill auto:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4yK4.png)

**sh run.sh** :

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Start Server.!"
cd /usr/games/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/ && dotnet MasterServer.dll
```

Comment: You have to make it as a service. Did you try that?

Comment: You have to wrap the compiled DLL within bash as Linux `cron` job.

Comment: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/dotnetNewWorkerWindowsServicesOrLinuxSystemdServicesInNETCore.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your application to run as a service, you can create a `systemd` service.

You can follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-3.1) tutorial (section Monitoring): the unit file should look like

```
[Unit]
Description=My Service

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/app/myservice/production
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/app/myservice/production/mysite.dll
Restart=always
RestartSec=15
SyslogIdentifier=mysite
User=www-data
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
Environment=DOTNET_PRINT_TELEMETRY_MESSAGE=false

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The unit says that your service will be identified as `mysite` in the system logs and will be run under the `www-data` user account.
`WorkingDirectory` and `ExecStart` are obvious, while the line `WantedBy=multi-user.target` instructs the system to run it as startup. Omit it to have it on-demand.

For systemd configuration, you can have a look at [this](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-create-systemd-service-unit-in-linux) guide.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the new (.net core 2.1 and up) `IHostedService`. It's a generic form of the web hosted service that you use in asp.net core. It makes your app run as a Windows service on Windows, and a systemd service on *nix.

Here is the Microsoft documentation on the subject.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/background-tasks-with-ihostedservice

There's also a github repo with a sample background service here:

https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/tree/release/2.1/samples/GenericHostSample